# Python MultiLevel Index on DataFrame. Access first row of first index level to apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a multi-level index dataframe.  Level 1 index contains a unique key, level 2 index contains a date for the level 1 index.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

fake_data=pd.DataFrame([(x,pd.to_datetime('04/01/2020')+relativedelta(months=y)) for x in list(range(0,11)) for y in list(range(0,11))],columns=['x','y'])
fake_data['z']=fake_data['x']*np.random.uniform(low=1,high=1000)
fake_data.set_index(['x','y'],drop=True,inplace=True)
```

The desired result is that for the start of level 1 index (groupby) and assign a new variable to the dataframe which contains the quarter which is based off of the values in the second level index.  How can I specifically access groupby level 1 index **and apply a function** which evaluates the level 2 index to generate the Quarter?

Pictured, the **RIGHT** panel is the desired result from the dataframe.

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poP3Y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) for extract second level and add [`DatetimeIndex.quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.quarter.html):

```
fake_data['qtr'] = fake_data.index.get_level_values(1).quarter
print (fake_data.head(20))
                       z  qtr
x y                          
0 2020-04-01    0.000000    2
  2020-05-01    0.000000    2
  2020-06-01    0.000000    2
  2020-07-01    0.000000    3
  2020-08-01    0.000000    3
  2020-09-01    0.000000    3
  2020-10-01    0.000000    4
  2020-11-01    0.000000    4
  2020-12-01    0.000000    4
  2021-01-01    0.000000    1
  2021-02-01    0.000000    1
1 2020-04-01  983.538088    2
  2020-05-01  983.538088    2
  2020-06-01  983.538088    2
  2020-07-01  983.538088    3
  2020-08-01  983.538088    3
  2020-09-01  983.538088    3
  2020-10-01  983.538088    4
  2020-11-01  983.538088    4
  2020-12-01  983.538088    4
```

If want always starting by `0` add [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
fake_data['qtr'] = pd.factorize(fake_data.index.get_level_values(1).quarter)[0]
print (fake_data.head(20))
                      z  qtr
x y                         
0 2020-04-01   0.000000    0
  2020-05-01   0.000000    0
  2020-06-01   0.000000    0
  2020-07-01   0.000000    1
  2020-08-01   0.000000    1
  2020-09-01   0.000000    1
  2020-10-01   0.000000    2
  2020-11-01   0.000000    2
  2020-12-01   0.000000    2
  2021-01-01   0.000000    3
  2021-02-01   0.000000    3
1 2020-04-01  80.286425    0
  2020-05-01  80.286425    0
  2020-06-01  80.286425    0
  2020-07-01  80.286425    1
  2020-08-01  80.286425    1
  2020-09-01  80.286425    1
  2020-10-01  80.286425    2
  2020-11-01  80.286425    2
  2020-12-01  80.286425    2
```